# Copy variables into one buffer and read it

Tags: c, buffer, store

I created three buffers and variables and copied every variable to the according buffer.

Then I took the pointers from the buffer and printed it.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    // Buffers.
    unsigned char a_buffer[sizeof(int)];
    unsigned char b_buffer[sizeof(int)];
    unsigned char c_buffer[sizeof(float)];

    // Variables ressources.
    int a = 65500;
    int b = 32000;
    float c = 3.14;

    // Variables pointers.
    int *aa = NULL;
    int *bb = NULL;
    float *cc = NULL;

    /* Copy variables to buffer. */
    memcpy(a_buffer, &a, sizeof(int));
    memcpy(b_buffer, &b, sizeof(int));
    memcpy(c_buffer, &c, sizeof(float));

    /* Set pointers. */
    aa = (int*) a_buffer;
    bb = (int*) b_buffer;
    cc = (float*) c_buffer;

    // Print values.
    printf("%i %i %f\n", *aa, *bb, *cc);

    return 0;
}
```

Output: `65500 32000 3.140000`

Now I like to store these variables into one buffer and wrote this.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    // Buffer.
    unsigned char buffer[sizeof(int) + sizeof(int) + sizeof(float)];

    // Buffer pointer (first object).
    unsigned char *buf_ptr = buffer;

    // Variables ressources.
    int a = 65500;
    int b = 32000;
    float c = 3.14;

    // Variables pointers.
    int *aa = NULL;
    int *bb = NULL;
    float *cc = NULL;

    /* Copy variables to buffer. */
    uint16_t cur = 0;
    memcpy(buf_ptr + cur, &a, sizeof(int));
    cur += sizeof(int);
    memcpy(buf_ptr + cur, &b, sizeof(int));
    cur += sizeof(int);
    memcpy(buf_ptr + cur, &c, sizeof(float));
    cur += sizeof(float);

    /* Set pointers. */
    cur = 0;
    aa = (int*) buf_ptr + cur;
    cur += sizeof(int);
    bb = (int*) buf_ptr + cur;
    cur += sizeof(int);    
    cc = (float*) buf_ptr + cur;
    cur += sizeof(float);

    // Print values.
    printf("%i %i %f\n", *aa, *bb, *cc);

    return 0;
}
```

Output: `65500 2054246226 0.000000`

The first variable is correct, the second changes always, and the third is always zero.

What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: Too many flaws to comment on. For astarter: Do not use casts unreflected, but only if really required and you really know what you are doing (you do not!). an array is not a pointer. SO is no tutorial, you have a **specific** problem - state it. Use a debugger, but first read & understand a C book/tutorial! Do not skip chapters.

Comment: For your actual question, the short answer is probably that you need parenthesis around the (buf_ptr + cur). For example bb = (int*)(buf_ptr + cur) I believe will do what you want; I'm not answering yet because I haven't tried it.

Comment: What makes you think `cc = (float*) buf_ptr + cur;` will work?  Try what you're doing on an architecture that has any address restrictions and you'll likely wind up with `SIGSEGV` or `SIGBUS`.

Comment: @clausismus Just for the record, are you sure you need **float c = 3.14;** and not **double c = 3.14;**

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that it looks like you're adding the wrong offset due to the pointer type when doing the `aa = (int *)buf_ptr + cur` section.

Use `aa = (int *)(buf_ptr + cur)` instead (and correspondingly for the other pointer assignments).

Here is an ideone that does this, looks like it works: https://ideone.com/64awsM

The reason is this: when you cast `buf_ptr` to `(int *)`, you're saying treat this as a pointer to an integer (which is what you want).
But then you add an offset `cur` to that pointer, so if you were thinking of `buf_ptr` as an array, you're accessing `buf_ptr[cur]` where each element is an `int`. Since you have `cur=sizeof(int)` (which is probably 4 or 8), you are quickly leaving the range of your buffer. If you keep `buf_ptr` as a char array, your offsets are single bytes as you expected, and you only perform the cast at the end.

This also explains why your first element was always correct (since you basically are doing `buf_ptr[0]`, it doesn't matter what the element size is since the offset is zero).